# How can i merge old and new objects in one array without creating an object inside object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const array = [{
  "id": "1",
  "main": [{
    "type": "a",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 1
  }],
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "main": [{
    "type": "b",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "main": [{
    "type": "c",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "main": [{
    "type": "d",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}]
```

From above object, i want to combine id- 2,3 and 4 into one key which has 3 objects.

```
const result = [array.reduce((acc, {id, main}) => {
  const { nu, role, type } = main[0]
  const hash = `${nu}-${role}`;
  acc[hash] = acc[hash] ? [{ ...acc[hash] }, {type: type, id: id }] : 
{ type, id: [id] };
  return acc;
}, {})];
```

#### Expected:

[image]

Example:

```js
const array = [{
  "id": "1",
  "main": [{
    "type": "a",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 1
  }],
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "main": [{
    "type": "b",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "main": [{
    "type": "c",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "main": [{
    "type": "d",
    "nu": '0',
    "role": 2
  }],
}]

const result = [array.reduce((acc, {id, main}) => {
  const { nu, role, type } = main[0]
  const hash = `${nu}-${role}`;
  acc[hash] = acc[hash] ? [{ ...acc[hash] }, {type: type, id: id }] : 
{ type, id: [id] };
  return acc;
}, {})];

console.log(result);
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong, can someone please help ?

Comment: Why just keys 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: @mstephen19 then : "Why main is an array containing only one object ?" Is it necessary ?

Comment: @r0ulito also good question

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: You have JSON inside array, where is the object?

Comment: @RitikBanger There is no JSON in the question. A JavaScript object literal is not JSON.

Comment: why do you have arrays for `id` and do you really want a single object or array, depending of the count of items in a group? why not in this case use always an array? it would make handling easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the arrays with an object and a common key with padded zeroes at start.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "1", main: [{ type: "a", nu: "0", role: 1 }] }, { id: "2", main: [{ type: "b", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }, { id: "3", main: [{ type: "c", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }, { id: "4", main: [{ type: "d", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { id, main }) => {
        main.forEach(({ type, nu, role }) => {
            const key = `${nu.toString().padStart(3, 0)}-${role}`;
            (r[key] ??= []).push({ id, type });
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For getting an exact result, like in picture, you could wrap `id` of the first object of a group in an array and if a group has more than one object take an array.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "1", main: [{ type: "a", nu: "0", role: 1 }] }, { id: "2", main: [{ type: "b", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }, { id: "3", main: [{ type: "c", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }, { id: "4", main: [{ type: "d", nu: "0", role: 2 }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { id, main }) => {
        main.forEach(({ type, nu, role }) => {
            const key = `${nu.toString().padStart(3, 0)}-${role}`;
            r[key] = r[key]
                ? [].concat(r[key], { id, type })
                : { id: [id], type };
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `result["000-1"].id` and `result["000-2"][0].id` should be arrays.

Comment: why only this items?

Comment: It's the expected result in the question.

Comment: @jabaa, sometimes op have errors in the wanted data. it could be here, too.

Comment: It's not my downvote. I'm just informing you that this is not the expected behavior. If you assume a wrong output in the question, you should probably first clarify it in the comment section.

Comment: please see edit.